# Can't 'reverse' the months listed in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android-datepicker

I want to 'reverse' the months listed in the spinner displayed in the DatePickerDialog.

DatePickerDialog uses the widget, android.widget.DatePicker, to populate the day, the month and the year spinners. For example, when calling the private method setCurrentLocale() to popluate the month spinner, the widget populates its member variable, mShortMonths.

```
private void setCurrentLocale(Locale locale) {
:
:
:
   mShortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
:
```

You find that the class, DateFormatSymbols, returns the string array, "[Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]", from the device's default locale, Locale.getDefault()

I'm told, LocaleData.get() returns a shared LocaleData for the given locale. And so, I was thinking I could 'adjust' the shared local value by using the public member, LocaleData.shortMonthNames:

```
import libcore.icu.ICU;
import libcore.icu.LocaleData;
:
:
   transient LocaleData localeData;

   localeData = LocaleData.get(Locale.getDefault());

   ArrayUtils.reverse(LocaleData.shortMonthNames);
```

With that, it's then hoped, when again populating the spinners, I will get the months in reverse:

```
mShortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
```

"[Dec, Nov, Oct, Sep, Aug, Jul, Jun, May, Apr, Mar, Feb, Jan]"

When I try to implement this approach, I'm getting the error, 'The import libcore cannot be resolved' with the following import statements.

```
import libcore.icu.ICU;
import libcore.icu.LocaleData;
```

Why would these import statements produce this error when those very same import statements are working just fine while debugging and stepping through the class, DateFormatSymbols, for example??

Comment: I have the same problem, could you find the answer?